# WPF visual studio like ToolBar "Add and remove buttons" menu

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to make a customized toolbar control like below:

[image]

The main window can have multiple toolbars, they are all created backgroundly.
What I need is make all the toolbars contains a "Add or Remove Buttons" menu.
It should work exactly like how visual studio does. You can show/hide items by checking the menu items under the "Add or Remove Button" menu.

Now the challenging part is how to make a "Add or Remove Button" control work exactly like visual studio. It seems wpf doesn't come with this kind of control....

When mouse hover the "Add or Remove button" the checkable menuitems should keep showing.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the link it appears to be broken for me but if you are talking about the little "down" arrow in VS that allows you to add new buttons then my first though is to use a context menu, which is available in wpf.